# Can we change SVG Image width and height dynamically in react native?

Tags: image, react-native, svg, keyboard-events, svg-animate

I'm trying to find the way to change the dimensions of the SVG when the `KeyboardWillShow` and  `KeyboardWillHide` listener occurs. For example, using React native Animated prop we can change the image dimensions using `Animated.Image`. So how can we do the same with SVG image? any help would be appreciated.

**Here is what I'm trying to do :**

```
const keyboardListenerShow = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillShow' : 'keyboardDidShow';

const keyboardListenerHide = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillHide' : 'keyboardDidHide';      
  
        useEffect(() => {
    
        Keyboard.addListener(keyboardListenerShow, _listnerShow);
        Keyboard.addListener(keyboardListenerHide, _listerHide);
    
        return () => {
          Keyboard.removeListener(keyboardListenerShow, _listnerShow);
          Keyboard.removeListener(keyboardListenerHide, _listerHide);
        }},[])
    
      const svgDimensions = useRef( new Animated.Value(200)).current;
    
      const _listnerShow = (event) => {
        Animated.timing(svgDimensions, {
          duration: event.duration,
          toValue: 80,
          useNativeDriver:false,
        }).start();
      };
    
       const _listerHide = (event) => {
        Animated.timing(svgDimensions, {
          duration: event.duration,
          toValue: 200,
          useNativeDriver:false,
        }).start();
      };
```

**Example:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyxoE.jpg

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?